# Videocall in Skype causes closing session on Ubuntu 12.04, x86?

Tags: 12.04, skype

Strange problem with videocalling on Skype.
Installation of Skype passed unremarkably and normal calls working fine. But when trying to do video call turning on the camera of the partner causes closing of the session,with black screen flashing for a second displaying an error message in command line, then appearing the logon screen. After logon all programs are closed, but the opened before disk partitions are still mounted.

Sometimes videocall goes fine, and problem appears after 4-5 minutes. In some cases after some such "restarts"call can be done without interruption for more than half an hour. But the lasti time it was breaking each 5 minutes ofr 4 times in a row, so finally I have to switch to Windows.

What can be the reason? Maybe a problem with the camera driver, becouse crash happens only in my computer. The laptop is older one - HP Probook 4510s, with built-in camera. With the previous Ubuntu and Skype versions never had such problems
Ubuntu 12.04 is a clear install after formatting the partition (due to unsuccessful upgrade to 12.10). Skype was installed trough Software center

Answer (score 0):

It can be driver problem , but you can do one thing, upgrade your graphic driver via additional driver package in ubuntu , it will show mostly 1-2 more advanced graphics drivers such as ATI/AMD Catalyst™ Mobility ... etc. install it and after that try to make skype call.

Comment: All additional drivers already installed. No update available. Skype with the latest stable version - just reinstalled afer download from the official site

Answer (score 0):

Update the kernel (http://www.upubuntu.com/2013/02/installupgrade-to-linux-kernel-379-in.html) then go back to video call and try it again.

Comment: Updating the kernel led to lost of all internet connections (both wired and wireless) and disappearing of the icon for network. No success to install drivers becouse wired connection was not recognized. 3G modem also did't work, so I was forced to remove the new kernel.

Comment: Finally I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 with kernel 3.5 and the problem solved (but I have to fight with the video driver problem known for Xorg1.13 , kernel 3.5 and ATI 13.1 drivers)